# angular directive compile order

Tags: hyperlink, compilation, angularjs, directive

I was trying to write a simple directive to generate a (potentially) more complex dom element. I am quite confused about what is going on here but I think the directive I use inside my directive get linked first? Anyway the element I am generating is not visible where it should.

Sorry for all that confusion, here is the plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/vWxTmA1tQ2rz6Z9dJyU9?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think the directive I use inside my directive get linked first?

Yes.  A child directive's link function will execute before the parent's link function.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/xfh3F/) that shows two nested directives,

```
<div d1>
  <div d2></div>
</div>
```

and it logs when the directives' controller and link functions are called.

---

There are a few issues with your Plunker:

Since you are using `@` for your isolate scopes, you need to use {{}}s in your attribute values:

```
<visible value='{{visible}}'>plop</visible>
<invisible value='{{visible}}'>plop</invisible>
```

Since `$scope.visible` is defined in your controller, I assume you meant to use that value, and not `test`.

In the `invisible` directive, you need to use isolate scope property `value` in your link function.  Property `visible` is available to the transcluded scope (which is in affect if you use a `template` in your directive like @Langdon has) but not the isolate scope, which is what the link function sees.

```
var template = "<span ng-show='value'>{{value}}</span>";
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p7EmUctUIovk1PDpm3if?p=preview).

Comment: Hi @Mark do you know how I can get ng-show to be linked after my directive? Can I call its link function manually after the $compile call?

Comment: @Reno, I don't know how you could call the link function.  However, see my updated answer regarding making your Plunker work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a *simple* directive, you're better off letting Angular do most of the work through `ngTransclude`, and `$watch`.

**http://plnkr.co/edit/xYTNIUKYuHWhTrK80qKJ?p=preview**

HTML:

```
  <!doctype html>
      <html ng-app="app">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>trying to compile stuff</title>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.1/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
          <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="test" id="test" /><label for="test">Visibility (currently {{test}})</label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <visible value='test'>visible tag</visible>
            <invisible value='test'>invisible tag</invisible>
          </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = false;
  })
  .directive('visible', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      template: '<span ng-transclude></span>',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        value: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(attrs);

        scope.$watch('value', function (value) {
          element.css('display', value ? '' : 'none');
        });

        console.log(attrs.value);
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('invisible', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E', 
      transclude: true,
      template: '<span ng-transclude></span>',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        value: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('value', function (value) {
          element.css('display', value ? 'none' : '');
        });
      }
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi Langdon, thanks for your solution! I wanted to avoid using watch if possible as it seems to impact on performance, ng-show should do the trick here if I can get it to be linked *after* my directive...

Comment: @Reno, the watch expression associated with `scope.$watch('value',...`) will be evaluated just as often (i.e., every Angular digest cycle) as a watch expression that gets associated with ng-show.